# Check if NodeJS ClearTextStream stream is "ended"?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a ClearTextStream for a TLS connection and I want to check if "end" was already called. The actual problem is, that I'm trying to write something into the stream and I get an "write after end" error.

Now to avoid that, I just want to check if "end" was already called. I do have an "close" event, but it isn't fired in all cases.

I can't find it in the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_cleartextstream) and I couldn't find anything like that by googling.

I could check the error event (which is throwing "write after end" for me) and handle the situation there - but is there really no way to check this in the beginning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a `write after end` error, that means that you are trying to write data to a `Writable` stream that has been closed (ie. that can't accept anymore input data). When a writable stream closes, the `finish` event is emitted (see [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish)). On the other hand, the `close` event is emitted by a `Readable` stream, when the underlying resource is closed (for instance when the file descriptor you are reading is closed).

As a `ClearTextStream` is a `Duplex` stream, it can emit both `close` and `finish` events, but they don't mean the same thing. In your particular case, you should listen to the `finish` event and react appropriately.

Another solution would be to check the `this.ended` and `this.finished` booleans (see [the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.11/lib/_stream_writable.js#L60-L63)), but I wouldn't recommend that as they are private variables and only reflect the implementation details, not the public API.